# Code igniter - running two queries collide

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

As part of a very large active records query in CI, I need to get something from a different model - something like:

```
$sql = $this->events_model->events_to_sql($val); //returns an sql
$this->db->where($sql, NULL, false);
```

Now "events_to_sql" run a different query to get some data it needs for it to operate, but it fails because it uses an Active Records "where" from before, where the first query is not closed.

```
$this->db->where("clients.email !=", '');
```

How can I tell CI: This is a separate query. You shall run it and only it?

*No, I can not run the other query first, because there are multiple of the same idea, and I don't want each case t be handled separately, but all to be handled in the same manner.

*I know I can use another DB connection, but I'd rather work with a single connection.

EDIT:

This is what runs: (in order)

```
//main model
$this->db->where("clients.email !=", '');
//Events to sql function
  //run seperate function
   $this->db->from('events');
   return $this->db->get();
return (string)$sql_built_from_the_event_stuff.
```

Instead of getting: "SELECT * FROM events" I get "SELECT * FROM events WHERE clients.email != ''"

Comment: have you tried `$this->db->close();`  query at the end of `events_to_sql`

Comment: Can you add the function `events_to_sql()` ?

Comment: @Astro This will also "destroy" all of the rules I setted before running the function.

Comment: @SankarV added the order of actions happening and sub functions (simplified)

Comment: if you want `SELECT * FROM events`, why you are using this, `$this->db->where("clients.email !=", '');`  or just add a condition to separate query like `if(condition){$this->db->where("clients.email !=", ''); }` @Amit

Comment: @Astro Because some-when later in the code, this "where" is utilized. The other query I run is just to add a where to my big query. I cannot change the order of things, so I want to know if there is a way to run the query 'separately' from the main one

Comment: Yes, use any dummy variable to separate the query. can you explain what  is the use of `$val` argument, you are not using it on `events_to_sql()` function.  I hope argument may differ based on the process, so use `$val` to separate query or add argument like `$separate`

Answer (score 0):

Use arguments to separate query, 
Example:

```
$separate = 1;
$sql = $this->events_model->events_to_sql($val,$separate); //returns an sql
$this->db->where($sql, NULL, false);
```

Model events_to_sql,

```
public function events_to_sql($val, $queryselector = false){
   .....
   .....
if($queryselector != 1){
   $this->db->where("clients.email !=", '');
}
//Events to sql function
  //run seperate function
   $this->db->from('events');
   return $this->db->get();
return (string)$sql_built_from_the_event_stuff.
}
```

Comment: I'm calling this function from a totally separate model, so mixing up stuff is not good in this case. Also, I don't know in advance what are the query's where - its not only    $this->db->where("clients.email !=", '');